# Can we safely distribute password protected .p12 file?

Tags: certificates

I have a password protected `.pfx` file and I would like to know if it safe to share it on GitHub.

The intention is to ensure that companies can trust a `dll` file of the Tweetinvi open source library. The DLL is signed by a certificate and the `.p12` file contains both private and public key.

This has been requested by big companies and I do not know how secure a password protected `.p12` file is.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I have updated the content of the question.

Comment: Are you sure yo need to share the private key too? Who is actually signing the DLL? If this is you, then all you need to share is the public key, it is sufficient to check the signature validity and does not expose any private information.

Comment: I am actually signing it, but for commodity I was wondering if it was possible to share both private and public if they were protected by the password. To let other developers working with me having the .p12 directly from github (without having to send it by email).

Comment: @Linvi a password can eventually be bruteforced so I wouldn't share it publicly.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will therefore only have the certificate store locally.

Comment: You should read about best practices for signing private keys. You generally try to take great care with them and would never think of sharing. Keeping them on a single computer that is used for nothing but signing is more appropriate

Comment: This makes no sense.  If you distribute the private key, no one can know for sure that your the only one that can sign things with it.  It defeats the whole purpose.  These 'big companies' don't need the private key to trust and they should know better.  If they don't you should inform them.

Comment: My intention was not to giveaway the private key. I was asking if it the private key was safe in password protected .p12. Apparently it is not.

Comment: In best case scenario, each signer should have their own key pair, so you don't need to share your own signing key. This keeps accountability to each signer.

Comment: Also note the default cipher used by many utilities to export pkcs12 is not very strong. Recent windows and OpenSSL seems to use 3DES. Older windows uses RC4...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By having the file, it would be possible to try to brute force the password, so you would need to choose a really strong password to protect it and make brute forcing infeasible. Eg I can find on google tools that claim to brute force PKCS#12 at 500k passwords per second. If you choose 8 *random* printable characters it would take more than 400years. That on a comercial tool with GPU acceleration.  Looks safe enough for your scenario.

However, sharing the key with other developers should be avoided anyway. Since you will need to share securelly the password anyway by another channel, and you should chose a password that is really strong, maybe you can use the same channel to securelly share the PKCS#12, and,  if not, sending both using two separate distinct and private channels still is a better option.